# How to connect var javascript with text?

Tags: javascript

How to connect var javascript with text ?

```
var xxx = 5;
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: ($("validate_focus"+xxx).offset().top - page_height_val/2)}, 'slow');
```

on code i want to connect 
var `xxx` with text `validate_focus`

to `validate_focus5`

But not work , How can i do that ?

Comment: I think validate_focus is CLASS or ID. so you need add $("#validate_focus"+xxx) or $(".validate_focus"+xxx)

Answer (score 0):

That's the correct way to do but you're missing the selector:

```
var xxx = 5;
$('html, body').animate({ 
      scrollTop: 
        ($(".validate_focus"+xxx)
     //    ^^^ use . if it is class, use # if it is id
          .offset().top - page_height_val/2)
 }, 'slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like ...

```
$("#validate_focus"+xxx)
```

... if `validate_focus5` is a Id, or ...

```
$(".validate_focus"+xxx)
```

... if `validate_focus5` is a Class.